# Merge of two complicated JSON objects

Tags: python, json, merge

I want to merge two JSON objects into a new one. I try to use jsonmerge with a complete json schema, but i dont know how to set the merge strategies right. I am pretty sure it can be done.

Code:

```
import json
from jsonmerge import Merger
from jsonschema import validate
full_build = {
         "captures": [
            {
               "compiler": "gnu",
               "executable": "gcc",
               "cmd": ["gcc", "options", "file1.cpp"],
               "cwd": ".",
               "env": ["A=1", "B=2"],
            },
            {
               "compiler": "gnu",
               "executable": "gcc",
               "cmd": ["gcc", "options", "file2.cpp"],
               "cwd": ".",
               "env": ["A=1", "B=2"],
            }
         ]
}
incremental_build = {
         "captures": [
            {
               "compiler": "gnu",
               "executable": "gcc",
               "cmd": ["gcc", "new options", "file2.cpp"],
               "cwd": ".",
               "env": ["A=1", "NEW=2"],
            },
            {
               "compiler": "gnu",
               "executable": "gcc",
               "cmd": ["gcc", "options", "file3.cpp"],
               "cwd": ".",
               "env": ["A=1", "B=2"],
            }
         ]
}
schema = {
   "type" : "object",
   "properties" : {
      "captures": {
         "type" : "array",
         "items" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
               "cmd" : {
                  "type" : "array",
                  "items" : {"type" : "string"},
               },
               "compiler" : {"type" : "string"},
               "cwd" : {"type" : "string"},
               "env" : {
                  "type" : "array",
                  "items" : {"type" : "string"},
               },
               "executable" : {"type" : "string"},
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
validate(instance=full_build, schema=schema)

mergeSchema = schema
merger = Merger(mergeSchema)
result = merger.merge(full_build, incremental_build)
print(json.dumps(result, indent=3))
```

Result:

```
{
   "captures": [
      {
         "compiler": "gnu",
         "executable": "gcc",
         "cmd": [
            "gcc",
            "options",
            "file3.cpp"
         ],
         "cwd": ".",
         "env": [
            "A=1",
            "B=2"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
   "captures": [
      {
         "compiler": "gnu",
         "executable": "gcc",
         "cmd": [
            "gcc",
            "options",
            "file1.cpp"
         ],
         "cwd": ".",
         "env": [
            "A=1",
            "B=2"
         ]
      },
      {
         "compiler": "gnu",
         "executable": "gcc",
         "cmd": [
            "gcc",
            "new options",
            "file2.cpp"
         ],
         "cwd": ".",
         "env": [
            "A=1",
            "NEW=2"
         ]
      },
      {
         "compiler": "gnu",
         "executable": "gcc",
         "cmd": [
            "gcc",
            "options",
            "file3.cpp"
         ],
         "cwd": ".",
         "env": [
            "A=1",
            "B=2"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

There are more things to consider (like having more or fewer options/environment variables then before), but I think with a little hint i will manage to complete the task.
I really dont want to hard code it.

And no, i cannot change the structure of the json :(.

Background: I want to merge SonarQube build wrapper outputs, because i dont want to do a full build to get all files into the wrapper output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you don't really need any complex merge operation at all. You basically want to combine the ‘captures’ lists from both structures into a new structure which contains all of them. This can be achieved by making a copy and simply extending the list afterwards:

```
full_build = ...
incremental_build = ...
combined = copy.deepcopy(full_build)
combined['captures'].extend(incremental_build['captures'])
```

If you want to ‘deduplicate’ based on some attribute, e.g. the file name, you can use something like this:

```
def get_filename_from_capture(cmd):
    return cmd["cmd"][-1]


all_captures = full_build["captures"] + incremental_build["captures"]
captures_by_filename = {
    get_filename_from_capture(capture): capture for capture in all_captures
}

combined = copy.deepcopy(full_build)
combined["captures"] = list(captures_by_filename.values())
```

Comment: This results in 4 `captures` array elements with `"file2.cpp"` twice. The `"file2.cpp"` should be only once and be the one from `incremental_build`

Comment: extended the answer to ‘dedup’ based on some arbitrary value

Comment: Thanks. I would need to edit `get_filename_from_capture` for better recognition of the filename (it may be anywhere), but this should work!

Comment: yeah i figured you would need something smarter, which is why i extracted that into a helper. good luck. (and mark the answer as accepted!)

Answer (score 4):

You have two arrays of JSON objects and based on them you want to construct a single array.

In your example, it seems that sometimes you want objects from `incremental_build` to overwrite those from `full_build` (there is only one object that mentions `file2.cpp` in the final array), but sometimes you don't (the object with `file3.cpp` doesn't overwrite the object with `file1.cpp`).

You didn't specify what exactly the rule for this should be, but I'm guessing the file name is what you want to match against. I'm also guessing that you want to treat the array elements themselves as immutable and don't want to further merge them together when the file name matches.

To achieve this, you can use the following schema:

```
schema = {
   "properties" : {
      "captures": {
         "mergeStrategy": "arrayMergeById",
         "mergeOptions": {
            "idRef": "/cmd/2"
         },
         "items": {
            "mergeStrategy": "overwrite"
         }
      }
   }
}

merger = Merger(schema)
result = merger.merge(full_build, incremental_build)
```

You don't need a full schema, unless you want to also validate your JSON. `jsonmerge` by itself only cares about the merge strategy information.

The above schema specifies that the array under the property *captures* in the top-level object should be merged using the `arrayMergeById` strategy. This strategy merges elements of an array based on a value pointed to by the `idRef` reference. In your example, the file name is the third element of the `cmd` property (JSON pointers use zero-based indexing).

`arrayMergeById` merges matching array elements based on their own schemas. By default they would be merged using `objectMerge` strategy. This would produce a wrong result in the case where an element in `incremental_build` would be missing a property that is present in the matching `full_build` element. Hence the above schema also specifies the *overwrite* strategy for all items of `captures` array.

Comment: Thanks avian. This works, but the filename is not allways at index 2 :(. I guess wouter bolsterlee answer works better in this use case.